# How do I make a Javascript class a child of another class

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and have came across the call and prototype.constructor methods but don't have enough knowledge to make them work properly. Can some one fill in the knowledge I am missing. Here an Administrator is a User.

```
    function User(user) {
      this.id = user.id;
      this.email = user.email;
      this.firstname = user.firstname;
      this.lastname = user.lastname;
      this.age = user.age;
    }       

    User.prototype.fullName = function(){
        return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname
    }

    function Admin(admin){
        this.writer = admin.writer;
        this.editor = admin.editor;
        this.publisher = admin.publisher;
        //User.call(this);
    }

    Admin.prototype.fullAccess = function(){
        return (this.writer && this.editor && this.publisher);
    }

    //Admin.prototype = new User();
    //Admin.prototype.constructor = Admin;

    var user1 = new User({
        'id': 1,
        'email': 'sd_brown@ntlworld.com', 
        'firstname': 'Stephen',
        'lastname': 'Brown',
        'age': 44
    });

    var user2 = new User({
        'id': 2,
        'email': 'johndoe@ntlworld.com', 
        'firstname': 'John',
        'lastname': 'Doe',
        'age': 25
    });

    var admin1 = new Admin({
        'writer': true,
        'editor': true, 
        'publisher': true,
    });

    var admin2 = new Admin({
        'writer': true,
        'editor': true, 
        'publisher': false,
    });
```

Comment: [Reference link](http://alexsexton.com/blog/2013/04/understanding-javascript-inheritance/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there, it works with a few simple changes:

1. Uncomment your commented lines
2. Change `User.call(this);` to `User.call(this, admin);`. This will pass the parameters passed to the Admin constructor ahead to the "super" constructor.
3. Change `Admin.prototype = new User();` to `Admin.prototype = new User({});` (pass an empty object, otherwise the User constructor will throw an error for trying to access properties of undefined). Or just use `Admin.prototype = Object.create(User.prototype);` (polyfill required for IE<=8).

http://jsfiddle.net/P6ADX/

Comment: please check out how I'm eliminating the problem with the need to pass 'defaults' to create a prototype object: http://metadea.de/V/

Comment: Thats great, its nearly working. Only thing is I'm getting the error - 
TypeError: admin1.fullAccess is not a function when I try accessing it.

Comment: Switching the lines around seems to have fixed it....

`Admin.prototype = new User({});
Admin.prototype.constructor = Admin;
  
Admin.prototype.fullAccess = function(){
  return (this.writer && this.editor && this.publisher);
}`

Comment: @StephenBrown Glad you figured that out, I'm too late! :-)

Comment: @metadings I didn't have enough time to understand your library in depth, but I'll keep it bookmarked and come back to it later. Looks like you put a lot of effort there - although my personal js coding style is to usually avoid classical inheritance patterns.